# How to modify the facebook share button?

Tags: css

How can I modify the width of that fricken button? I have a retweet button that is the width that I like, but I cant seem to find any documentation on how to reduce the width in css for the facebook share button.

If you look at the posts buttons you will see it on the site. [www.itjourneyman.com](http://www.itjourneyman.com) you will see the facebook button is just a little wider then the retweet button making things look funny.

Does anyone know where I can find the css for that button without having to mod the actual plugins code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this css. You could tweak the right button padding to make it a little smaller. I used 4px in firefox and it looks good. I hope this helps. If you don't want to mess with the plugin code you would probably have to overwrite this CSS somewhere in your own CSS file. It's probably easier just to update the plugin CSS.

```
FBConnectButton_Small .FBConnectButton_Text {
margin-left:17px;
padding:2px 4px 3px;
}
```

Comment: I added in these changes and I dont think that they are the correct styles. Nothing changed. I looked in the plugins php file and I dont see any css really in there. I will keep looking I guess. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Ah, your right. The plugin is including this style directly from facebook.com http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect.php/en_US/css/connect-button-css/bookmark-button-css/share-button-css/FB.Connect-css/connect-css

You will have to override the CSS to make a custom size.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the `width` attribute:

**Add this:**

```
 style="width:100"
```

To your tag with the background image of the Facebook button in it. Change the width to whatever you need it to be.

Comment: I am using a facebook share plugin and I dont want to edit the plugin's code. I am using thesis theme and it comes with a custom.css style sheet that I want to make sure I use for all changes. I have been trying to play with the .FBConnectButton_Text 
{
font-size: 8px;
}
I think I am on the right track but I just want to find the style that will let me reduce the width of the whole thing to the same width as the retweet button.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer I did not add in the important.

```
.FBConnectButton_Text 
{
font-size: 8px;
padding:2px 4px 3px !important;
}
```