# How do you add FBConnectButton?

Tags: html, facebook

I see several websites such as macrumors.com using a Facebook button that is dark blue with their facebook logo and the word share on it... looking at code it says its called FBConnectButton, but a google search for it turns up nothing useful, nor is it obvious on the Facebook website.

This post refers to it as well, but not where the code originated from:

[How to modify the facebook share button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127940/how-to-modify-the-facebook-share-button)

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

That's the old `fb:share-button`, you should probably be using `fb:like` these days, as `fb:share-button` has been phased out.